# R: using grepl, how to only list that is true

Tags: r, list, grepl

I have a list of data and I'm trying to divide them into AM and PM groups.

I did

```
df1 <- split(start, grepl('PM', start$StartTime))
```

which split my list into AM/PM groups. However I only want to view those that evaluate to be `TRUE` (i.e. the PMs).

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Create the index `index <- grepl('PM', start$StartTime)` To get the rows with 'PM' only `start[indx,]` and for `AM`, `start[!indx,]`

Comment: If you have already split it, then `df1[["TRUE"]]` should get you the `PM` only list element

Comment: I would upvote if there were an example dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to akrun's suggestion:

```
subset(start, grepl('PM', StartTime))
```